Can ArcGIS Pro create virtual fields?
I need to be able to calculate the difference in months between a set date saved in a field and the current date. The Feature will be symbolised according to the resulting number of months. The original project was made in QGIS, but seems not possible with ArcGIS Pro.
Is this capability available for ArcGIS Pro?

Esri does not support the concept of virtual fields in ArcGIS Pro.  However, usually virtual fields are used for something like symbology or labeling, and Esri does offer Arcade expressions as an alternative for creating derived values for symbology or labeling.
Since this question appears related to symbology, following Set custom expressions for symbology - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation and using a Michigan county data set I had readily available, I added a new DATE field to the Michigan county data set and populated it with random dates between 1980 and 2020.  I then created an Arcade expression as a 'Custom' field for symbolizing months between now and that random date.
DateDiff(Now(), $feature.RAND_DATE, 'months')

The results are:

